# Handle 21 decimals number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an input range component in JavaScript, the component works with integers to define `max`, `min` and `step` values.

If the user provides a decimal `step` value, the component will use this function to get the number of decimals and transform it to an integer:

```
export function getDecimals(num) {
  const stepArr = num.toString().split('.');
  return stepArr[1] ? stepArr[1].length : 0;
}
```

Doing so, the component can work with integers, and when it needs to return to the user the value inserted by the user (using the range handle), it will convert the number back to a decimal number and set the decimals to the same amount provided by `step` with this function:

```
parseFloat(
  newValue.toFixed(getDecimals(this.props.step))
);
```

`this.props.step` is the original `step` value provided by the consumer of the component.

It works pretty well, but I received a bug report where one of the consumers receives a `RangeError` because the provided `step` number is:

```
0.000020735346383538284
```

This number has 21 decimal digits, while `Number.toFixed` supports no more than 20 decimal digits.

Here's a repro:

```js
const step = 0.000020735346383538284;

function getDecimals(num) {
  const stepArr = num.toString().split('.');
  return stepArr[1] ? stepArr[1].length : 0;
}

function toSafe(num) {
  return parseFloat(num.toFixed(getDecimals(step)));
}

console.log(toSafe(10));
```

I could easily fix this with:

```
export function getDecimals(num) {
  const stepArr = num.toString().split('.');
  return Math.min(20, stepArr[1] ? stepArr[1].length : 0);
}
```

But in this case I'd lose the precision required by the `step` value, because I would never return a value with more than 20 decimal digits.

How could I handle this case to preserve the precision?

**update**:

Would this function work or is it going to mess up some numbers because of the string manipulation?

```
export function toFixed(num, decimals) {
  const parts = num.toString().split('.');
  return Number(`${parts[0]}.${(parts[1] || '').slice(0, decimals)}`);
}
```

Comment: If you only need to return to the user, the original step value they provided, why not just store the original inputted step value and then just give it back to them later instead of worrying about converting it to an integer and then back to a decimal?

Comment: I may be not clear enough, I'm returning the value input by the user using the range handle, so it gets computed by my component. I updated the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess would be to use some sort of big number library.  Something like [this](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Please add it as a comment.

Comment: I would like to avoid to import a whole library just to handle this not so common edge case actually.

Comment: Also, the library you linked seems to handle no more than 15 decimal digits?

Comment: Why should this be a comment?  It answers the question!  The native JS implementation can only handle 20 digits (probably some sort of double), so you need to use a generic library.  TBH, that was the first hit when I googled "bignumber library js".  I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: @Fez That library supports arbitrary length numbers, but it only accepts js numbers up to 15 decimal places.  With these sorts of libraries, you need to use them all the time, not just when you want to do some conversion.

Comment: But I need to input a 21 precise number, I don't just need to keep the precision during the computations

Comment: Yes, so the input is a string, but as soon as you receive it, you convert it to a bignumber.

Comment: my input is a number... 